# Java: fit data to a Gamma distribution (scale, shape needed)

Tags: java, r, math, statistics

Is there a Java library which I can use to fit a given data vector to a Gamma distribution, in order to find out its shape and scale. Something like  `fitdistr(data,'gamma')` in R?

I can only find librarys which calculate a sample distribution from given shape and scale parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a closed form solution for Gamma MLE, but you can easily implement the procedure described [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/minka-gamma.pdf) (p.2). Apache commons has the needed digamma function.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [SSJ package](https://github.com/umontreal-simul/ssj) (Apache 2 license). It provides [parameters estimations from observed data](http://umontreal-simul.github.io/ssj/docs/master/classumontreal_1_1ssj_1_1probdist_1_1GammaDist.html#a78681a0473a45aee584f6840aa25e0d6) for the Gamma distribution.

```
GammaDist dist = GammaDist.getInstanceFromMLE(data, data.length);
double alpha = dist.getAlpha();
double lambda = dist.getLambda();
```